# "run as administrator" in standard user account

Tags: windows-vista, privileges, runas

how can I run command prompt as administrator from a standard user account?  The "run as" does not appear to work, neither does the CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER trick.  I think it is because I am logged in as a standard privilaged account.  Is it possoible to "run as administrator" from this type of a restricted account?   I have the administrator password, I just need to be prompted somehow.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: one of the tags was Vista, so I assume that

Comment: Are you connected to a work domain or is it just a standalone computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the reason it was not prompting me for the password was because I had all of the other administrator accounts deactivated... so I just had to activate one of the administrator accounts using net user admin /active:yes

Answer (score 4):

If you type

```
cmd
```

into the search box after clickining on the Windows Orb, right click on the program and select

```
Run as Administrator
```

It will prompt you for the admin password and then start the command processor as admin and in the c:\windows\system32 directory

Comment: Actually I figured out that the reason it was not prompting me for the password was because I had all of the other administrator accounts deactivated... so I just had to activate one of the administrator accounts using net user admin /active:yes

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows XP/2000, then check whether "Run As" or "Secondary Logon" services are started in your system. See this page for more info:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676

If you are using Windows Vista and if "Run As" does not seem to work, then you can try an app called "ShellRunas":
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't there, but I have not used that feature since XP so not sure if that is an error or on purpose.

If I was you, I would do the following:

1. Open Notepad
2. Paste the following:

   ```
   runas /user:administrator cmd
   ```
3. Save this is on your desktop as anything with the extension of .cmd or .bat
4. Run this and you should be able to start command prompt as the user, after typing the password.

(assuming user Administrator, change to whatever name you need!)

Comment: The /profile switch can be added if the user profile needs to impersonated as well. Check this link: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q254094

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the command prompt icon in windows the second item in the right-click-menu is "Run as.."    Its easier than doing it from the command line as the previous answer suggests.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe UAC is turned off, had it on a W7 pc.
Take a look at RunasSpc (www.robotronic.de) if you want a limited user run a program/installer with adminrights without him/her knowing the password. Works for me fabulous with Ninite installer (ninite.com) on XP and W7